# How to groupby one column, sort the value by another column and then condense the sorted values of another column into a list?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I want to groupby my id column, and then sort by the year column, and then finally collapse the data in such a way that I have a list of years in the years column and a list of another data point in another column while preserving the order.

For example:

We would start with a data frame like

```
df = pandas.DataFrame( { 
    "id" : [2957, 1456, 2223, 1456, 1456, 2957, 2223, 2957, 2223] , 
    "year" : [2018, 2017, 2018, 2016, 2018, 2016, 2017, 2017, 2016],
    "rating" : [3, 1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 1, 1] }
```

Which would appear in a data frame like

```
    id  year    rating
0   2957    2018    3
1   1456    2015    1
2   2223    2018    2
3   1456    2016    2
4   1456    2017    3
5   2957    2016    2
6   2223    2017    3
7   2957    2017    1
8   2223    2016    1
```

I would then like to sort the data by year ascending, group the data by id, and then condense the data in such a way that there would be a single row for each unique id where the year and rating columns would be collapsed into lists with their orders preserved.

The end result would look something like

```
    id          year         rating
0   2957 [2016, 2017, 2018] [2,1,3]
1   1456 [2015, 2016, 2017] [1,2,3]
2   2223 [2016, 2017, 2018] [1,3,2]
```

I understand how to group by and sort by characters, however, I am having trouble condensing the data into lists.

Comment: your example has typo

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.groupby()` + `.agg(list)`:

```py
out = df.sort_values(by="year").groupby("id").agg(list).reset_index()
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
     id                year     rating
0  1456  [2015, 2016, 2017]  [1, 2, 3]
1  2957  [2016, 2017, 2018]  [2, 1, 3]
2  2223  [2016, 2017, 2018]  [1, 3, 2]
```

Comment: You really should be closing these as duplicates. They have been asked many times before...

Answer (score 0):

**Example**

your example has typo

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame( { 
    "id" : [2957, 1456, 2223, 1456, 1456, 2957, 2223, 2957, 2223] , 
    "year" : [2018, 2017, 2018, 2016, 2018, 2016, 2017, 2017, 2016],
    "rating" : [3, 1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 1, 1]})
```

**Code**

use groupby + agg + list

```
(df.sort_values('year')
   .groupby('id').agg(list)
   .reindex(df['id'].unique())
   .reset_index())
```

output:

```
    id      year                rating
0   2957    [2016, 2017, 2018]  [2, 1, 3]
1   1456    [2016, 2017, 2018]  [2, 1, 3]
2   2223    [2016, 2017, 2018]  [1, 3, 2]
```